# With Firebase persistence, .childRemoved is not called when a child is removed*

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running into a problem making sure data is synced with the database when using persistence. Before you run away I just have a question about a specific behavior, and I want to know if I am doing something wrong or if this is expected behavior.

Here is the basic setup I am using:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

  // Gets cached or live data
  // Does all the things

  ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

     // Gets new children added
     // Adds the things

  }

  ref.observe(.childRemoved) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

     // Gets removed children
     // Removes the things

  }

}
```

This works great in most use cases. When on the screen showing the data, in this case, a comments feed, The Data is added and removed perfectly.

More importantly, when coming back to a previously visited comment feed, the cache is loaded and then .childAdded is fired for every new comment that is not included in the cache. That's great.

The problem I am running into is when coming back to a previously visited comment feed where comments have been deleted while away. **.childRemoved does not get invoked for each comment that has been deleted.** Which is leaving stale data on the screen. I can see how this might be the expected behavior considering the data has been deleted and thus a snapshot is unavailable to be sent.

If that is the case, what would be the correct course of action to be sure a user is not presented a comment that has been deleted?

Let me know if any clarification is needed! Thank you.

Comment: In the case with the problem, does the observeSingleEvent not fire (and hence the childRemove never get added) or does the observeSingleEvent fire, but the childRemoved not?

Comment: The observeSingleEvent does fire in my testing, as well as the childAdded. And the childRemoved does invoke if a child is removed while the listener is active. But if a child was deleted while 'away', upon returning it is not invoked. My current assumption is this is just not how the API functions and I am going to have to change my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening here is a subtle race caused by the persistence behavior.

When you call observe, you set up a listener which will update as changes occur. When you call "observeSingleEvent", you generally do the same thing, but stop listening after the first result. However, with persistence enabled that first result will usually come from the cache. The call will, however, call a background update.

What I believe is happening here is:

- Comment is deleted in comment feed while there are no listeners
- The single event is attached, and the cached state including the deleted comment is returned
- The comment feed is updated *before* the childRemoved listener is added
- The childRemoved listener is added and does not fire

That said, I haven't repro'd this to validate for sure. One test though would be to setup the single event as a regular listener, and just cancel the listener one you receive one event. In connected states, that should prefer getting state from the backend, so you should see the comment feed with the comment deleted (the comment removed would never fire, but thats because the initial state would be coherent).